# Signout after user disconnects on Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

For those of you who have used flask-login will know the decorator `fresh_login_required`. I am trying to implement something similar by myself.

It doesn't have to be a decorator. I just want to be able to do some works after the user has been totally disconnected (example: closed the browser).
And is it a good idea to have a global integer variable to count the total active/online users?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The server has no way of knowing the difference between a user that has closed their browser and gone away and one who is still staring at your web page: it only knows what the browser tells it. And "global" variables aren't global at all if you have multiple processes (e.g. in a WSGI container).

Comment: Then how does the remember me button work and how is flask-login able to detect a fresh login?

Comment: @FahimFerdous If you want to know how flask-login does something, read its source code. ☺

Comment: I tried but it isn't clear how they've acheived it. All though the source is not too big but still I could not undestand if

Answer (score 1):

Flask sessions are handled by flask session interface. Flask-Login just check if the current session is fresh.

```
from flask import session

def login_fresh():
     '''
     This returns ``True`` if the current login is fresh.
     '''
     return session.get('_fresh', False)

def login_user():
    '''
    Your login code here
    '''
    session['_fresh'] = True 

def logout_user():

    '''
    Your logout code here
    '''
    if '_fresh' in session:
        session.pop('_fresh')
```

The code snippet above is from Flask-Login source code,that can be accessed [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login/utils.py). If you needs the user to login again, just check if his login is fresh.

Comment: But it sets the value by itself. Both of the values.

Comment: I have checked it out. but the key/value is set by the module itself and not flask...

Comment: Yes, but the session is still handled by Flask-Session, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with:

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = False
```

From the docs:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.session.permanent

Comment: But when I check the value of session.new it always says false. And if I redirect after inspecting the value, the browser complains that it is not redirecting properly and suggests that it might happen because of the cookies being disabled